# Sonarlink plugin not getting installed in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarlint

I am trying to install the `sonarlint` plugin from eclipse marketplace. Once I install it shows as installed in the eclipse marketplace. However after restarting eclipse is reporting below errors. Can you please help. I have installed the `2020-03 version of eclipse` but still the same issue.Can someone please help

**ERROR -1**

```
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.sonarlint.eclipse.cdt [484]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.cdt.core; resolution:="optional"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.sonarlint.eclipse.core
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.sonarlint.eclipse.core; bundle-version="7.0.0.37874"; singleton:="true"
       org.sonarlint.eclipse.core [485]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=11))"
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.sonarlint-core; bundle-version="5.1.0"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.sonarlint-core; bundle-version="7.0.0.37656"
              org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.sonarlint-core [489]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=11))"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.sonarlint-core
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.sonarlint-core; bundle-version="7.0.0.37656"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:1844)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1837)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1778)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1742)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1664)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)
```

**ERROR -2**

```
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.sonarlint.eclipse.core [485]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=11))"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.sonarlint-core; bundle-version="5.1.0"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.sonarlint-core; bundle-version="7.0.0.37656"
       org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.sonarlint-core [489]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=11))"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:1844)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1837)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1778)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1742)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1664)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)
```

**ERROR -3**

```
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.sonarlint.eclipse.jdt [486]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.sonarlint.eclipse.core
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.sonarlint.eclipse.core; bundle-version="7.0.0.37874"; singleton:="true"
       org.sonarlint.eclipse.core [485]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=11))"
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.sonarlint-core; bundle-version="5.1.0"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.sonarlint-core; bundle-version="7.0.0.37656"
              org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.sonarlint-core [489]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=11))"
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.sonarlint-core
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.sonarsource.sonarlint.core.sonarlint-core; bundle-version="7.0.0.37656"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:462)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:1844)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1837)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1778)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1742)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1664)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key message is

```
Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=11))"
```

This is saying that Eclipse must be run using Java 11 or later.

Comment: Ok thanks and where do I specify the version? in eclipse.ini in the -vm section?

Comment: Yes, the -vm in the eclipse.ini. Most of the current Eclipse downloads include a Java 15 built in.

Comment: Wouldn't this have failed well before this point?  It sounds like this person was able to start up Eclipse, and then attempt to install a plugin. They shouldn't have been able to do that if they were not running it with Java 11.

Comment: @DavidM.Karr It is the plug-in they installed that needs Java 11, different plug-ins can require different levels of Java. You can install plug-ins that need a newer version of Java than the one you are running, but they will give this error when they are started.

Comment: @DavidM.Karr You might be thinking of the `-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=11` entry in the eclipse.ini which lets the startup code do a quick check on the Java version

Comment: @greg-449 They're running 2020-03, doesn't that require Java 11 no matter what?

Comment: @DavidM.Karr No, it was 2020-09 that first required Java 11